# what is the relation between the image of $A$ and its rank

Tags: matrices

If $A$ is a linear transformation on an $n$-dimensional vector space 
then we know that 
$n=\dim(\ker(A)) + \dim (\mathrm{Im}(A))$
but why the $\dim(\mathrm{Im}A)$ is equal to the rank of $A$?

Comment: Isn't that the definition?

Comment: Have you defined the rank of a linear map? Or did you only define the rank of a matrix?

Comment: Please include your (or your text's) definitions of Im(A) and rank(A).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recall that given a matrix $A\in \mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$, there is an associated linear map $$T_A\colon \mathbb{R}^n\to \mathbb{R}^m:X\mapsto AX.$$
Here we view $X\in \mathbb{R}^n$ as a column (otherwise $AX$ is meaningless).

By the dimension theorem for linear maps, we have $$\dim(\mathbb{R}^n)=\dim(\ker(T_A))+\dim(\mathrm{im}(T_A)).$$

Now let $e_i$ be the $i$-th standard basis vector of $\mathbb{R}^n$ (viewed as a column). Convince yourself that $T_A(e_i)=Ae_i$ is simply the $i$-th column of $A$. Clearly $T_A(e_i)\in \mathrm{im}(T_A)$ for each $i$. In fact, $\mathrm{im}(T_A)$ is spanned by these vectors (why?). It follows that $\mathrm{im}(T_A)=C(A)$ where $C(A)$ is the column space of the matrix $A$.

At least from this explanation we may conclude that $\dim(\mathrm{im}(T_A))$ equals the *column rank* of $A$. It requires a bit more thought to conclude that the column rank and row rank of $A$ are equal.